# Why won't my Xamarin.Android project build with Proguard enabled: "java.exe" exited with code 1

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, proguard

I would like to use Proguard on my project, however I receive the java.exe error when I try to build.

```
"java.exe" exited with code 1.
```

I have tried increasing the heap size and creating a [proguard.cfg file as outlined here,](http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/190674/#Comment_190674) to no success.

I can build the project when I turn off Proguard, so I am confident it's the problem.

Any help?

EDIT: Adding output that looks relevant. I see one exception and many warnings, but I'm not sure how I could begin to address these.

```
5>Using "Proguard" task from assembly "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Build.Tasks.dll".
5>Task "Proguard" (TaskId:297)
5>  Task Parameter:ProguardJarPath=C:\Users\owner\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk\tools\proguard\lib\proguard.jar (TaskId:297)
5>  Task Parameter:JavaToolPath=C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_71\\bin (TaskId:297)
5>  Task Parameter:JavaPlatformJarPath=C:\Users\owner\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk\platforms\android-23\android.jar (TaskId:297)
5>  Task Parameter:MonoPlatformJarPath=C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v6.0\mono.android.jar (TaskId:297)
5>  Task Parameter:ClassesOutputDirectory=obj\Release\android\bin\classes (TaskId:297)
5>  Task Parameter:ProguardCommonXamarinConfiguration=obj\Release\proguard\proguard_xamarin.cfg (TaskId:297)
5>  Task Parameter:ProguardGeneratedReferenceConfiguration=obj\Release\proguard\proguard_project_references.cfg (TaskId:297)
5>  Task Parameter:ProguardGeneratedApplicationConfiguration=obj\Release\proguard\proguard_project_primary.cfg (TaskId:297)
5>  Task Parameter:ProguardConfigurationFiles=
5>          {sdk.dir}tools\proguard\proguard-android.txt;
5>          {intermediate.common.xamarin};
5>          {intermediate.references};
5>          {intermediate.application};
5>          proguard.cfg;
5>       (TaskId:297)
5>  Task Parameter:
5>      LibraryProjectJars=
5>          obj\Release\__library_projects__\AndroidTranscoder\library_project_imports\AndroidTranscode.jar
5>          obj\Release\__library_projects__\FormsViewGroup\library_project_imports\formsviewgroup.jar
5>          obj\Release\__library_projects__\OkHttp\library_project_imports\okhttp-2.3.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar (TaskId:297)
5>  Task Parameter:
5>      AdditionalJavaLibraryReferences=
5>          C:\Users\owner\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Android.Support.v4\21.0.3\embedded\classes.jar
5>          C:\Users\owner\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Android.Support.v4\21.0.3\embedded\libs\internal_impl-21.0.3.jar (TaskId:297)
5>  Task Parameter:ProguardJarInput=obj\Release\proguard\__proguard_input__.jar (TaskId:297)
5>  Task Parameter:ProguardJarOutput=obj\Release\proguard\__proguard_output__.jar (TaskId:297)
5>  Task Parameter:DumpOutput=obj\Release\proguard\dump.txt (TaskId:297)
5>  Task Parameter:PrintSeedsOutput=obj\Release\proguard\seeds.txt (TaskId:297)
5>  Task Parameter:PrintUsageOutput=obj\Release\proguard\usage.txt (TaskId:297)
5>  Task Parameter:PrintMappingOutput=obj\Release\proguard\mapping.txt (TaskId:297)
5>  Proguard (TaskId:297)
5>    JavaPlatformJarPath: C:\Users\owner\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk\platforms\android-23\android.jar (TaskId:297)
5>    MonoPlatformJarPath: C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v6.0\mono.android.jar (TaskId:297)
5>    ClassesOutputDirectory: obj\Release\android\bin\classes (TaskId:297)
5>    ProguardGeneratedApplicationConfiguration: obj\Release\proguard\proguard_project_primary.cfg (TaskId:297)
5>    ProguardJarInput: obj\Release\proguard\__proguard_input__.jar (TaskId:297)
5>    ProguardJarOutput: obj\Release\proguard\__proguard_output__.jar (TaskId:297)
5>    ProguardConfigurationFiles: (TaskId:297)
5>      
5>          {sdk.dir}tools\proguard\proguard-android.txt;
5>          {intermediate.common.xamarin};
5>          {intermediate.references};
5>          {intermediate.application};
5>          proguard.cfg;
5>       (TaskId:297)
5>    JavaSourceFiles: (TaskId:297)
5>    JavaLibraries: (TaskId:297)
5>    ExternalJavaLibraries: (TaskId:297)
5>    DoNotPackageJavaLibraries: (TaskId:297)
5>    LibraryProjectJars: (TaskId:297)
5>      obj\Release\__library_projects__\AndroidTranscoder\library_project_imports\AndroidTranscode.jar (TaskId:297)
5>      obj\Release\__library_projects__\FormsViewGroup\library_project_imports\formsviewgroup.jar (TaskId:297)
5>      obj\Release\__library_projects__\OkHttp\library_project_imports\okhttp-2.3.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar (TaskId:297)
5>    UseProguard: False (TaskId:297)
5>    EnableLogging: False (TaskId:297)
5>    DumpOutput: obj\Release\proguard\dump.txt (TaskId:297)
5>    PrintSeedsOutput: obj\Release\proguard\seeds.txt (TaskId:297)
5>    PrintMappingOutput: obj\Release\proguard\mapping.txt (TaskId:297)
5>  Environment Variables passed to tool: (TaskId:297)
5>    java_tool_options= -Dfile.encoding=UTF8 (TaskId:297)
5>    proguard_home=C:\Users\owner\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk\tools\proguard (TaskId:297)
5>  C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_71\\bin\java.exe -jar C:\Users\owner\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk\tools\proguard\lib\proguard.jar -include C:\Users\owner\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk\tools\proguard\proguard-android.txt -include obj\Release\proguard\proguard_xamarin.cfg -include obj\Release\proguard\proguard_project_references.cfg -include obj\Release\proguard\proguard_project_primary.cfg -include proguard.cfg "-injars 'obj\Release\proguard\__proguard_input__.jar';'C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v6.0\mono.android.jar';'obj\Release\__library_projects__\AndroidTranscoder\library_project_imports\AndroidTranscode.jar';'obj\Release\__library_projects__\FormsViewGroup\library_project_imports\formsviewgroup.jar';'obj\Release\__library_projects__\OkHttp\library_project_imports\okhttp-2.3.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar';'C:\Users\owner\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Android.Support.v4\21.0.3\embedded\classes.jar';'C:\Users\owner\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Android.Support.v4\21.0.3\embedded\libs\internal_impl-21.0.3.jar'" "-libraryjars 'C:\Users\owner\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk\platforms\android-23\android.jar'" -outjars "obj\Release\proguard\__proguard_output__.jar"  (TaskId:297)
5>  ProGuard, version 4.7 (TaskId:297)
5>  Reading input... (TaskId:297)
5>  Reading program jar [C:\Workspace\Mobile\Blert\Source\Blert\Blert.Droid\obj\Release\proguard\__proguard_input__.jar] (TaskId:297)
5>  Reading program jar [C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v6.0\mono.android.jar] (TaskId:297)
5>  Reading program jar [C:\Workspace\Mobile\Blert\Source\Blert\Blert.Droid\obj\Release\__library_projects__\AndroidTranscoder\library_project_imports\AndroidTranscode.jar] (TaskId:297)
5>  Reading program jar [C:\Workspace\Mobile\Blert\Source\Blert\Blert.Droid\obj\Release\__library_projects__\FormsViewGroup\library_project_imports\formsviewgroup.jar] (TaskId:297)
5>  Reading program jar [C:\Workspace\Mobile\Blert\Source\Blert\Blert.Droid\obj\Release\__library_projects__\OkHttp\library_project_imports\okhttp-2.3.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar] (TaskId:297)
5>  Reading program jar [C:\Users\owner\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Android.Support.v4\21.0.3\embedded\classes.jar] (TaskId:297)
5>  Reading program jar [C:\Users\owner\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Android.Support.v4\21.0.3\embedded\libs\internal_impl-21.0.3.jar] (TaskId:297)
5>  Reading library jar [C:\Users\owner\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk\platforms\android-23\android.jar] (TaskId:297)
5>  Initializing... (TaskId:297)
5>  Note: the configuration doesn't specify which class members to keep for class 'android.support.v4.view.ViewPager$OnPageChangeListener' (TaskId:297)
5>  Note: the configuration doesn't specify which class members to keep for class 'mono.android.support.v4.view.ViewPager_OnPageChangeListenerImplementor' (TaskId:297)
5>  Note: the configuration doesn't specify which class members to keep for class 'android.support.v4.view.ViewPager$PageTransformer' (TaskId:297)
5>  Note: the configuration doesn't specify which class members to keep for class 'android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout$DrawerListener' (TaskId:297)
5>  Note: the configuration doesn't specify which class members to keep for class 'mono.android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout_DrawerListenerImplementor' (TaskId:297)
5>  Note: the configuration doesn't specify which class members to keep for class 'android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayoutImpl' (TaskId:297)
5>  Note: the configuration doesn't specify which class members to keep for class 'android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout$OnRefreshListener' (TaskId:297)
5>  Note: the configuration doesn't specify which class members to keep for class 'mono.android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout_OnRefreshListenerImplementor' (TaskId:297)
5>PROGUARD : warning : net.ypresto.androidtranscoder.engine.MediaFormatValidator: can't find referenced class org.jcodec.codecs.h264.H264Utils
5>PROGUARD : warning : net.ypresto.androidtranscoder.engine.MediaFormatValidator: can't find referenced class org.jcodec.codecs.h264.io.model.SeqParameterSet
5>PROGUARD : warning : net.ypresto.androidtranscoder.engine.MediaFormatValidator: can't find referenced class org.jcodec.codecs.h264.io.model.SeqParameterSet
5>PROGUARD : warning : net.ypresto.androidtranscoder.engine.MediaFormatValidator: can't find referenced class org.jcodec.codecs.h264.H264Utils
5>PROGUARD : warning : net.ypresto.androidtranscoder.engine.MediaFormatValidator: can't find referenced class org.jcodec.codecs.h264.io.model.SeqParameterSet
5>PROGUARD : warning : net.ypresto.androidtranscoder.engine.MediaFormatValidator: can't find referenced class org.jcodec.codecs.h264.io.model.SeqParameterSet
5>PROGUARD : warning : okio.DeflaterSink: can't find referenced class org.codehaus.mojo.animal_sniffer.IgnoreJRERequirement
5>PROGUARD : warning : okio.Okio: can't find referenced class java.nio.file.Files
5>PROGUARD : warning : okio.Okio: can't find referenced class java.nio.file.Files
5>PROGUARD : warning : okio.Okio: can't find referenced class java.nio.file.Files
5>PROGUARD : warning : okio.Okio: can't find referenced class java.nio.file.Path
5>PROGUARD : warning : okio.Okio: can't find referenced class java.nio.file.OpenOption
5>PROGUARD : warning : okio.Okio: can't find referenced class java.nio.file.Path
5>PROGUARD : warning : okio.Okio: can't find referenced class java.nio.file.OpenOption
5>PROGUARD : warning : okio.Okio: can't find referenced class org.codehaus.mojo.animal_sniffer.IgnoreJRERequirement
5>PROGUARD : warning : okio.Okio: can't find referenced class java.nio.file.Path
5>PROGUARD : warning : okio.Okio: can't find referenced class java.nio.file.OpenOption
5>PROGUARD : warning : okio.Okio: can't find referenced class java.nio.file.Path
5>PROGUARD : warning : okio.Okio: can't find referenced class java.nio.file.OpenOption
5>PROGUARD : warning : okio.Okio: can't find referenced class org.codehaus.mojo.animal_sniffer.IgnoreJRERequirement
5>  Note: android.support.v4.text.ICUCompatIcs: can't find dynamically referenced class libcore.icu.ICU (TaskId:297)
5>  Note: com.squareup.okhttp.internal.Platform: can't find dynamically referenced class com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl (TaskId:297)
5>  Note: com.squareup.okhttp.internal.Platform: can't find dynamically referenced class org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.OpenSSLSocketImpl (TaskId:297)
5>  Note: android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompatJellybean accesses a declared field 'icon' dynamically (TaskId:297)
5>        Maybe this is program field 'android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat$Action { int icon; }' (TaskId:297)
5>        Maybe this is program field 'blert.droid.R$drawable { int icon; }' (TaskId:297)
5>        Maybe this is library field 'android.R$attr { int icon; }' (TaskId:297)
5>        Maybe this is library field 'android.R$id { int icon; }' (TaskId:297)
5>        Maybe this is library field 'android.app.LauncherActivity$ListItem { android.graphics.drawable.Drawable icon; }' (TaskId:297)
5>        Maybe this is library field 'android.app.Notification { int icon; }' (TaskId:297)
5>        Maybe this is library field 'android.app.Notification$Action { int icon; }' (TaskId:297)
5>        Maybe this is library field 'android.appwidget.AppWidgetProviderInfo { int icon; }' (TaskId:297)
5>        Maybe this is library field 'android.content.pm.PackageItemInfo { int icon; }' (TaskId:297)
5>        Maybe this is library field 'android.content.pm.ResolveInfo { int icon; }' (TaskId:297)
5>        Maybe this is library field 'android.inputmethodservice.Keyboard$Key { android.graphics.drawable.Drawable icon; }' (TaskId:297)
5>        Maybe this is library field 'android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech$EngineInfo { int icon; }' (TaskId:297)
5>  Note: android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompatJellybean accesses a declared field 'title' dynamically (TaskId:297)
5>        Maybe this is program field 'android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat$Action { java.lang.CharSequence title; }' (TaskId:297)
5>        Maybe this is program field 'blert.droid.R$id { int title; }' (TaskId:297)
5>        Maybe this is library field 'android.R$attr { int title; }' (TaskId:297)
5>        Maybe this is library field 'android.R$id { int title; }' (TaskId:297)
5>        Maybe this is library field 'android.app.Notification$Action { java.lang.CharSequence title; }' (TaskId:297)
5>        Maybe this is library field 'android.preference.PreferenceActivity$Header { java.lang.CharSequence title; }' (TaskId:297)
5>  Note: android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompatJellybean accesses a declared field 'actionIntent' dynamically (TaskId:297)
5>        Maybe this is program field 'android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat$Action { android.app.PendingIntent actionIntent; }' (TaskId:297)
5>        Maybe this is library field 'android.app.Notification$Action { android.app.PendingIntent actionIntent; }' (TaskId:297)
5>  Note: the configuration refers to the unknown class 'com.google.vending.licensing.ILicensingService' (TaskId:297)
5>  Note: the configuration refers to the unknown class 'com.android.vending.licensing.ILicensingService' (TaskId:297)
5>  Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'android.support.v4.view.ViewPager { void setOnAdapterChangeListener(android.support.v4.view.ViewPager$OnAdapterChangeListener); }', but not the descriptor class 'android.support.v4.view.ViewPager$OnAdapterChangeListener' (TaskId:297)
5>  Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'android.support.v4.view.ViewPager { void calculatePageOffsets(android.support.v4.view.ViewPager$ItemInfo,int,android.support.v4.view.ViewPager$ItemInfo); }', but not the descriptor class 'android.support.v4.view.ViewPager$ItemInfo' (TaskId:297)
5>  Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'android.support.v4.view.ViewPager { void calculatePageOffsets(android.support.v4.view.ViewPager$ItemInfo,int,android.support.v4.view.ViewPager$ItemInfo); }', but not the descriptor class 'android.support.v4.view.ViewPager$ItemInfo' (TaskId:297)
5>        You should check if you need to specify additional program jars. (TaskId:297)
5>PROGUARD : warning : there were 20 unresolved references to classes or interfaces.
5>           You may need to specify additional library jars (using '-libraryjars'). (TaskId:297)
5>  Note: there were 2 references to unknown classes. (TaskId:297)
5>        You should check your configuration for typos. (TaskId:297)
5>  Note: there were 3 unkept descriptor classes in kept class members. (TaskId:297)
5>        You should consider explicitly keeping the mentioned classes (TaskId:297)
5>        (using '-keep'). (TaskId:297)
5>  Note: there were 3 unresolved dynamic references to classes or interfaces. (TaskId:297)
5>  Note: there were 3 accesses to class members by means of introspection. (TaskId:297)
5>        You should consider explicitly keeping the mentioned class members (TaskId:297)
5>        (using '-keep' or '-keepclassmembers'). (TaskId:297)
5>  java.io.IOException: Please correct the above warnings first. (TaskId:297)
5>      at proguard.Initializer.execute(Initializer.java:321) (TaskId:297)
5>      at proguard.ProGuard.initialize(ProGuard.java:211) (TaskId:297)
5>      at proguard.ProGuard.execute(ProGuard.java:86) (TaskId:297)
5>      at proguard.ProGuard.main(ProGuard.java:492) (TaskId:297)
5>  Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS:  -Dfile.encoding=UTF8 (TaskId:297)
5>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(1815,3): error MSB6006: "java.exe" exited with code 1.
5>Done executing task "Proguard" -- FAILED. (TaskId:297)
5>Done building target "_CompileToDalvik" in project "Blert.Droid.csproj" -- FAILED.: (TargetId:241)
```

Comment: Look under console output for more information to this error. It could be a missing file or wrong filename for example.

Comment: `java.io.IOException: Please correct the above warnings first` ... You have to fix them if you want the error to go away

Comment: Does SDK manager suggests any updates? Do you have jdk updates available or inconsistent versions? Just suggestions, since I have no clue ;)

Comment: hi friend. I have exactly the same error than you. Could you solve it?

Comment: Were you able to resolve these issues? Particularly "20 unresolved references to classes or interfaces"?

Comment: Refer my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38147828/java-exe-exited-with-code-1-proguard-issue/41355484#41355484

Comment: What was the resolution to this issue? I'm having the same problem when ProGuard is checked. Tried using symbolic links for both Java and AndroidSDK

Answer (score 5):

Answer can be found in this thread.

[Xamarin.Android Proguard - Unsupported class version number 52.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39514518/xamarin-android-proguard-unsupported-class-version-number-52-0/39514706#39514706)

You will also need to copy the below files from your old proguard into the new folder.

- proguard-android.txt
- proguard-android-optimize.txt
- proguard-project.txt

Answer (score 2):

this may help someone. my issue was with the proguard.cfg encoding as described here:
https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/deployment,_testing,_and_metrics/proguard/#Troubleshooting

try opening the cfg file in notepad++. if the encoding is "Encode in UTF-8 BOM" you need to save the file with "Encode in UTF-8"

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the following line your Proguard.cfg file:

```
-dontwarn okio.**
```

If that doesn't help, add these as well:

```
-dontwarn org.jcodec.codecs.h264.** 
-keep class org.jcodec.codecs.h264.** {*;}
```

Answer (score 1):

All i had to do was upgrade the proguard to the latest version found here: https://sourceforge.net/projects/proguard/files/

On macOS the location of the Proguard directory if using Xamarin Studio/Visual Studio for Mac is here:

```
/Users/your_username/Library/Developer/Xamarin/android-sdk-macosx/tools/proguard/bin
```

Answer (score -1):

Could you try increase the Java heap size to `1G` in your project properties/options

Comment: How does that help "20 unresolved references to classes or interfaces"?