# Xamarin.Android Proguard - Unsupported class version number 52.0

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, android-proguard

I'm trying to use Proguard in my Xamarin.Android project, yet the compilation fails with the error `Unsupported class version number [52.0] (maximum 51.0, Java 1.7)`

I saw from those [two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23170502/proguard-says-unsupported-class-version-number-52-0-maximum-51-0-java-1-7-w) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22670059/error-proguard-unsupported-class-version-number) that it may be a mismatch between Java 7 and Java 8, more precisely some versions of proguard don't support Java 8. However in Xamarin Preferences -> SDK Location, Java SDK points to JDK 7 : `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_79.jdk/Contents/Home`

Is there any place where proguard can be configured more precisely ? Any other idea ?

Here's the failure log :

> java.io.IOException: Can't read
>   [/Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.Android.framework/Versions/7.0.0-18/lib/xbuild-frameworks/MonoAndroid/v7.0/mono.android.jar]
>   (Can't process class [android/app/ActivityTracker.class] (Unsupported
>   class version number [52.0] (maximum 51.0, Java 1.7)))    at
>   proguard.InputReader.readInput(InputReader.java:230)  at
>   proguard.InputReader.readInput(InputReader.java:200)  at
>   proguard.InputReader.readInput(InputReader.java:178)  at
>   proguard.InputReader.execute(InputReader.java:78)     at
>   proguard.ProGuard.readInput(ProGuard.java:196)    at
>   proguard.ProGuard.execute(ProGuard.java:78)   at
>   proguard.ProGuard.main(ProGuard.java:492) Caused by:
>   java.io.IOException: Can't process class
>   [android/app/ActivityTracker.class] (Unsupported class version number
>   [52.0] (maximum 51.0, Java 1.7))  at
>   proguard.io.ClassReader.read(ClassReader.java:112)    at
>   proguard.io.FilteredDataEntryReader.read(FilteredDataEntryReader.java:87)
>     at proguard.io.JarReader.read(JarReader.java:65)    at
>   proguard.io.DirectoryPump.readFiles(DirectoryPump.java:65)    at
>   proguard.io.DirectoryPump.pumpDataEntries(DirectoryPump.java:53)  at
>   proguard.InputReader.readInput(InputReader.java:226)  ... 6 more
>   Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Unsupported class
>   version number [52.0] (maximum 51.0, Java 1.7)    at
>   proguard.classfile.util.ClassUtil.checkVersionNumbers(ClassUtil.java:140)
>     at
>   proguard.classfile.io.ProgramClassReader.visitProgramClass(ProgramClassReader.java:88)
>     at proguard.classfile.ProgramClass.accept(ProgramClass.java:346)    at
>   proguard.io.ClassReader.read(ClassReader.java:91)     ... 11 more
>
> 9 Warning(s)    1 Error(s)

Answer (score 115, accepted):

You need to update the default Android SDK `proguard.jar` with the latest version of Proguard found here:

https://sourceforge.net/projects/proguard/files/

I would recommend that you install this on the side of the default version that Android ships in `android-sdk\tools\proguard`. Simply rename the existing folder to something else and add the new version of `proguard`.

This is listed in the Xamarin.Android 7.0 release notes:

https://developer.xamarin.com/releases/android/xamarin.android_7/xamarin.android_7.0/

In which the following bug was logged as well:

https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=44187

Which is coordinated with a Pull Request in the Xamarin.Android repository:

https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-android/pull/209

Comment: This works for me, for the details I replace the Android `tools/proguard/lib` folder by the `lib` folder inside the latest Proguard release from sourceforge (5.3.2 at this time).

Comment: If you replace the whole proguard directory, make sure to copy the config files from the old directory: proguard-android-optimize.txt, proguard-android.txt, proguard-project.txt.

Comment: The most fantastic thing is that it really helps even 2 years ago )
Thx man, you've saved my day.

Comment: this solution works even if you have the latest version. sometimes you may get the error, just redownload and replace with the existing. I dont know why but it works like that

Comment: Thank you very much @GuillaumePerrot

Turns out replacing the whole proguard folder can not fix the problem but replacing the proguard/lib can.

Answer (score 4):

I had a problem where Proguard was removing the Google Play Services libraries from my app.

In addition to following [@Jon Douglas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1048571/jon-douglas)' answer above, I had to add the following lines of text to the `proguard-android.txt` file found in this folder:

`/(Path to your Android SDK Folder)/tools/proguard`

```
-keep public class com.google.android.gms.* { public *; }
-dontwarn com.google.android.gms.**
```

## Complete proguard-android.txt File

```
-keep public class com.google.android.gms.* { public *; }
-dontwarn com.google.android.gms.**

# This is a configuration file for ProGuard.
# http://proguard.sourceforge.net/index.html#manual/usage.html

-dontusemixedcaseclassnames
-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclasses
-verbose

# Optimization is turned off by default. Dex does not like code run
# through the ProGuard optimize and preverify steps (and performs some
# of these optimizations on its own).
-dontoptimize
-dontpreverify
# Note that if you want to enable optimization, you cannot just
# include optimization flags in your own project configuration file;
# instead you will need to point to the
# "proguard-android-optimize.txt" file instead of this one from your
# project.properties file.

-keepattributes *Annotation*
-keep public class com.google.vending.licensing.ILicensingService
-keep public class com.android.vending.licensing.ILicensingService

# For native methods, see http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/examples.html#native
-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
    native <methods>;
}

# keep setters in Views so that animations can still work.
# see http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/examples.html#beans
-keepclassmembers public class * extends android.view.View {
   void set*(***);
   *** get*();
}

# We want to keep methods in Activity that could be used in the XML attribute onClick
-keepclassmembers class * extends android.app.Activity {
   public void *(android.view.View);
}

# For enumeration classes, see http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/examples.html#enumerations
-keepclassmembers enum * {
    public static **[] values();
    public static ** valueOf(java.lang.String);
}

-keepclassmembers class * implements android.os.Parcelable {
  public static final android.os.Parcelable$Creator CREATOR;
}

-keepclassmembers class **.R$* {
    public static <fields>;
}

# The support library contains references to newer platform versions.
# Don't warn about those in case this app is linking against an older
# platform version.  We know about them, and they are safe.
-dontwarn android.support.**

# Understand the @Keep support annotation.
-keep class android.support.annotation.Keep

-keep @android.support.annotation.Keep class * {*;}

-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
    @android.support.annotation.Keep <methods>;
}

-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
    @android.support.annotation.Keep <fields>;
}

-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
    @android.support.annotation.Keep <init>(...);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

**Simple Answer**

According to documentation you need update proguard version (starting from [version 5](https://sourceforge.net/projects/proguard/files/proguard/) it support Java 8 ) and make sure you are using jdk1.8

JDK 1.8 - up to API 24+

JDK 1.7 - up to API 23

JDK 1.6 - up to API 20

***how to update***  from package console write this command

```
PM> Install-Package name.atsushieno.proguard.facebook
```

https://www.nuget.org/packages/name.atsushieno.proguard.facebook

or download [proguard](https://sourceforge.net/projects/proguard/files/proguard/) manually and replace it with current version

YOUR_SDK --> tools --> proguard --> (delete all old files , unzip new version )

**Detailed Answer** if you enable target android Nogut and you enable Multi-Dex or ProGuard  you need use proper ProGuard  version (as ToolMakerSteve said they have dependency on ProGuard)
so make sure you target java 8 from tools ->options ->xamarin ->java  and update ProGuard version

**Update Answer**

make sure your support library version compatible with target version , if you target

**Android 7** (api 24) mean your support library should be 24

**Android 7.1** (api 25 ) mean your support library should be 25

to all support library and if you using google play services as well

Answer (score 2):

I was also facing the same issue on my Windows 10 x64 and visual studio 2015. I have set the JDK path to JDK 1.8 under android settings in Visual studio 
tools ->options  ->xamarin ->java development kit location.  it was pointing to "C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_55" and I made it to "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_31", and issue has been fixed.

Comment: Does changing the path fixed this issue??

Comment: No it does not work for me, whether I use Java 7 or Java 8 in VS/Xamarin Studio I get the same error.

Comment: This does **not fix** the problem, if using **ProGuard or Multi-Dex**, because those depend on a tool inside android sdk/tools/proguard, as described in Jon Douglas answer. On the other hand, it **should fix** the problem for anyone **not using either ProGuard or Multi-Dex**, if they are getting this error trying to use Nougat [API 24], or some package/library that depends on an API 24 feature.

Answer (score 1):

**Using Visual Studio**

If you are using Visual Studio 2017 or 2019, please note that these applications pack their proguard.  For 2019, proguard version: 5.3.2.  For me, I needed version 6.0.3, so I made a backup of the proguard.jar file at:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\proguard\lib
```

And copied the latest one from zip from the sourceforge site.

Answer (score 0):

To get ProGuard work, you have to follow few steps

- First Download latest ProGuard file from [here](https://sourceforge.net/projects/proguard/files/), unzip and paste in your `android-sdk\tools\proguard` folder
- First you need to add proguard.cfg to your android project level.
- Change proguard.cfg file build action to ProguardConfiguration Change
- proguard.cfg file Encoding using Notepad++ to UTF-8

If you are getting warnings then you need to use -dontwarn attribute like below

```
-dontwarn com.symbol.emdk.**
-dontwarn org.apache.http.**
-dontwarn com.appdynamics.eumagent.runtime.**
```

You must need to remove/solve warning because that cause errors. Above code will remove all of your warnings.

If you are getting exception after executing your application you need to use -keep attribute. like below for required classes

```
-keep public class android.support.v7.widget.** { *; }
```