# Error when adding Xamarin.Firebase.Messaging 'java.exe exited with code 2'

Tags: xamarin

When I add the Xamarin.Firebase.Messaging library, my project generates an error that I am not able to solve, of the following error 'java.exe exited with code 2', what could be happening?

**Image error:**

[image]

Comment: Enable Diagnostic level logging for MSBuild and add the details of the error to your question (cut/paste the text for the error, please do not add images of text-based content) : https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/troubleshooting/troubleshooting/#Diagnostic_MSBuild_Output

Comment: You most likely need to move your Android SDK to a non-space path and ensure you apply https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39514518/xamarin-android-proguard-unsupported-class-version-number-52-0/39514706#39514706 as well.

Answer (score 0):

Adding Firebase in most applications will hit the 64k method limit in Java and thus require developers to use multi-dex.

A bug has been opened in Xamarin here: https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=55117

To work around the issue you can enable multi-dex as shown in the following screenshot:

[image]

On release builds, you can also try combining Proguard and Link All options but it requires more work to avoid any side effect to find everything to preserve.