# Error MSB6006: "java.exe" exited with code 1 when ProGuard enabled

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, android-proguard

I try to resolve this issue last few days, still without success.
If I build release version without proguard then everything is OK.

I read many topics about possible problems but nothing help in my case.
So far I did as follow:

1. Java max heap size - 1G
2. Use "mklink" - mklink /j C:\android-sdk “C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk”
3. Created own proguard.cfg with content:

> General Android
>   -dontwarn org.apache.http.**
>   -dontwarn android.net.http.AndroidHttpClient
>
> ## Android Support Library
>
> -keep class android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication
>
> -keep class android.support.v4.**
>
> -keep class android.support.v7.** {
>       public *; }
>
> ## Google Play Billing
>
> -keep class com.android.vending.billing.**
>
> ## Google Play Services
>
> -dontwarn com.google.android.gms.internal.*
>
> -keep class * extends java.util.ListResourceBundle {
>       protected java.lang.Object[][] getContents(); }

4. Manually update ProGuard to latest version.

And the result is 0 warnings and 1 error.

> ERROR:
>   **C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(1929,3):
>   error MSB6006: "java.exe" exited with code 1.**

What else can I do?
Please help.

**Update.**
I created brand new app "Xamarin Hello World" and there "ProGuard" works. So it must be something wrong with my app not a system. 
But visual studio doesn't show me any other error apart that Java code 1. So how to track where is a problem?

**UPDATE**
The problem was in my "proguard.cfg" file. I copy content from other source and one line there should be comment but it wasn't. So this problem gone. But now some warnings come out:

```
2>PROGUARD : warning : can't write resource [META-INF/MANIFEST.MF](Duplicate zip entry [classes.jar:META-INF/MANIFEST.MF]) 
2>Copying resources from program jar [G:\ApkiC-Sharp\GNote\GNote\GNote.Android\obj\Release\__library_projects__\Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Basement\library_project_imports\classes.jar](TaskId:345) 
2>PROGUARD : warning : can't write resource [META-INF/MANIFEST.MF] (Duplicate zip entry [classes.jar:META-INF/MANIFEST.MF]) 
2>Copying resources from program jar [G:\ApkiC-Sharp\GNote\GNote\GNote.Android\obj\Release\__library_projects__\Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Maps\library_project_imports\classes.jar] (TaskId:345) 
2>PROGUARD : warning : can't write resource [META-INF/MANIFEST.MF] (Duplicate zip entry [classes.jar:META-INF/MANIFEST.MF]) 
2>Copying resources from program jar [G:\ApkiC-Sharp\GNote\GNote\GNote.Android\obj\Release\__library_projects__\Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Tasks\library_project_imports\classes.jar] (TaskId:345) 
2>PROGUARD : warning : can't write resource [META-INF/MANIFEST.MF] (Duplicate zip entry [classes.jar:META-INF/MANIFEST.MF])
```

What dose it mean? Is it something to worried about?
How to check if "ProGuard" works fine?

Comment: Please refer to : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39514518/xamarin-android-proguard-unsupported-class-version-number-52-0/39514706#39514706

Comment: I read it before. Didn't help.

Comment: Try find more complete error message by using [Diagnostic MSBuild Output](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/troubleshooting/troubleshooting/#Getting_Diagnostic_Information).

Comment: Thank you. It helped, but other thing come out. Details above.

Comment: Are you using any **3rd-party** libraries that are adding it? It seems that some `Xamarin.GooglePlayServices` package  is **being included twice** in the set of code that `Proguard` is optimizing, and this isn't allowed.

Comment: I'm using geolocation, google maps, sqlite, plugin. Is it that you ask?

Comment: Is this just a warning? If it is and you can deploy the apk(after proguard) on you phone, you could ignore the warning.

Comment: It is warning. Yes I can deploy without any problem. Thank you for advice.

Answer (score 2):

I was also facing the same issue on my Windows 10 x64 and visual studio 2015. I have set the JDK path to JDK 1.8 under android settings in Visual studio tools ->options ->xamarin ->java development kit location. it was pointing to "C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_55" and I made it to "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_31", and issue has been fixed.

Comment: I tried to upgrade to Android 12 (but failed and had to rollback). The upgrade process installed a new java version (targeting that v12) and got set as default for JDK. Selecting the other one I had installed previously solved the issue (from `C:\Program Files\Microsoft\jdk-11.0.12.7-hotspot` to `C:\Program Files\Microsoft\jdk-11.0.10.9-hotspot`)

Comment: I suggest adding the new JDK route in `VS 2022`: `C:\Program Files\Microsoft\jdk-11.0.[XX].[Y]-hotspot` to this answer.

Answer (score -2):

Try enabling the  Multi-Dex compilation option.