# java.exe error while compiling xamarin-android application

Tags: java, xamarin, xamarin.android

i am developing an application, suddenly i started getting build error,

i have also tried increasing Heap size for java but nothing is working, can anyone help me put?

Here is the log....

```
>      > `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\\bin\java.exe -jar C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Xamarin\MonoForAndroid\AndroidSDK\build-tools\25.0.1\\lib\dx.jar
> --no-strict --dex --output=obj\Debug\android\bin obj\Debug\android\bin\classes "C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference
> Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v7.0\mono.android.jar"
> obj\Debug\__library_projects__\Telerik.Xamarin.Android.Common\library_project_imports\bin\Common.jar
> obj\Debug\__library_projects__\Telerik.Xamarin.Android.Data\library_project_imports\bin\Data.jar
> obj\Debug\__library_projects__\Telerik.Xamarin.Android.Gauges\library_project_imports\bin\Gauges.jar
> obj\Debug\__library_projects__\Telerik.Xamarin.Android.Input\library_project_imports\bin\Input.jar obj\Debug\__library_projects__\Telerik.Xamarin.Android.List\library_project_imports\bin\List.jar
> obj\Debug\__library_projects__\Telerik.Xamarin.Android.Primitives\library_project_imports\bin\Primitives.jar
> obj\Debug\__library_projects__\TwilioClient.Android\library_project_imports\bin\classes.jar
> obj\Debug\__library_projects__\TwilioClient.Android\library_project_imports\libs\org.apache.http.legacy.jar
> obj\Debug\__library_projects__\Xamarin.Android.Support.Animated.Vector.Drawable\library_project_imports\bin\classes.jar
> obj\Debug\__library_projects__\Xamarin.Android.Support.Compat\library_project_imports\bin\classes.jar
> obj\Debug\__library_projects__\Xamarin.Android.Support.Core.UI\library_project_imports\bin\classes.jar
> obj\Debug\__library_projects__\Xamarin.Android.Support.Core.Utils\library_project_imports\bin\classes.jar
> obj\Debug\__library_projects__\Xamarin.Android.Support.Design\library_project_imports\bin\classes.jar
> obj\Debug\__library_projects__\Xamarin.Android.Support.Fragment\library_project_imports\bin\classes.jar
> obj\Debug\__library_projects__\Xamarin.Android.Support.Media.Compat\library_project_imports\bin\classes.jar
> obj\Debug\__library_projects__\Xamarin.Android.Support.Transition\library_project_imports\bin\classes.jar
> obj\Debug\__library_projects__\Xamarin.Android.Support.v4\library_project_imports\bin\classes.jar
> obj\Debug\__library_projects__\Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat\library_project_imports\bin\classes.jar
> obj\Debug\__library_projects__\Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.RecyclerView\library_project_imports\bin\classes.jar
> obj\Debug\__library_projects__\Xamarin.Android.Support.Vector.Drawable\library_project_imports\bin\classes.jar
> C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Xamarin.Android.Support.CustomTabs\23.3.0.0\embedded\classes.jar
> 
>         1>  
>         1>  trouble writing output: Too many field references: 65539; max is 65536.
>         1>  You may try using --multi-dex option.
>         1>  References by package:
>         1>       2 android.accounts
>         1>      27 android.app
>         1>      24 android.content.pm
>         1>      10 android.content.res
>         1>      45 android.graphics
>         1>       2 mono.android.speech
>         1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(2068,3):
> error MSB6006: "java.exe" exited with code 2.
>         1>    DexOutputs: 
>         1>      obj\Debug\android\bin\classes.dex
>         1>Done executing task "CompileToDalvik" -- FAILED.
>         1>Done building target "_CompileToDalvikWithDx" in project "TestVoipApp.csproj" -- FAILED.
>         1>
>         1>Build FAILED.`
```

any  suggestion?

Comment: Please add the full build log as text to the question

Comment: please do NOT post error messages as images

Comment: added log and removed images.

Answer (score 3):

Turn on the **MultiDex**

Xamarin.Android -> Goto Properties -> AndroidOptions -> Enable MultiDex

Comment: i tried and got this error


Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error  Can't read [C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v7.0\mono.android.jar] (Can't process class [android/app/ActivityTracker.class] (Unsupported class version number [52.0] (maximum 51.0, Java 1.7))) TestVoipApp E:\Test\TestVOIP\TestAndroidClient\TwilioApp\CREATEMULTIDEXMAINDEXCLASSLIST

Comment: @Tayyab See this answer, may help you with this error you just mentioned; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39514518/xamarin-android-proguard-unsupported-class-version-number-52-0